# how to customize the PDF generated from jEuclid using MathML?

Tags: pdf, mathml

I can generate the **MathML** to **PDF** out using the jEuclid ("`mml2xxx.bat`") but what I get is a PDF with a size A4

What I need is, I want the PDF size exactly as per the equation in the PDF document

**What I got now :**

[image: this is a full size PDF output]

**What I need :**

[image: This is a cropped PDF just as the size of the equation]

Answer (score 0):

What is the intended destination of the PDF equation/expression? The reason I ask is that some applications are smart enough to know not to use the whole A4 size, and display just the math part. If you're using InDesign, for example, and you use the Place command to place this PDF into a document, it should appear at the proper size, and likely even with the correct baseline adjustment.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am doing this to create equation as PDF with only the page size of its contents is because I am going to use it in InDesign, Kindly give any idea to do this

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I didn't get a notification that you had commented again. I think if you just take the PDF from jEuclid and don't worry about its size, InDesign will know not to show the whitespace, and will place the expression correctly.